# Ordered Factorization of positive integers with two prime factors

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

The bottom of this page provides a solution to the number of ordered factorizations of a positive integer with two prime factors: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderedFactorization.html

i.e. if $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2}$

Then numbers of ordered factorizations is $$H(n) = 2^{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 - 1} \sum_{k=0}^{\alpha_2} {\alpha_1 \choose k}{\alpha_2 \choose k} 2^{-k}$$

And I am actually only interested in an easier version $m = \alpha_1 = \alpha_2$. In which case

$$G(p^m q^m) = 2^{2m - 1} \sum_{k=0}^{m} {m\choose k}{m\choose k} 2^{-k}$$

Is there a combinatoric argument to prove that result?  I found [the paper](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Ebchor/CLM.pdf) that proved it using generating function, but I'd be curious to see a combinatoric argument.

Also, how do I write $G(p^m q^m)$ as a generating function suppose we are able to infer this series through combinatoric argument?